# Mount a folder as a USB drive

Tags: mount, backup, fuse, google-drive

I'm on Linux Mint.

I'm trying to mount a folder so that the system recognizes it as a USB drive. To be able to specify file system type would be a bonus.

My end goal is to use `google-drive-ocamlfuse` to mount my Google Drive and use it to back up my system using BackInTime, TimeShift, and Aptik. Each of these three (and other backup solutions) support backing up your system to a USB drive, but don't support my fuse mount.

I've tried `mount --bind` and `mountfs`, but this isn't accomplishing what I need.

How can I backup my system to a specified Google Drive directory, having mounted it to my system to appear as if it's a physical USB?

Comment: Can you mount it as `usbfs` ? I am not really sure!

Comment: What would that look like? I'm still somewhat new in the world of Linux. `mountfs /home/user/GoogleDrive/ /GoogleDrive/` ?